# How can i know in what part of the project are referenced jquery script and bootstrap scripts?

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, twitter-bootstrap

I'm starting a new WebForm project.
What i see in the Site.Master are the following references:

```
<asp:ScriptReference Name="jquery" />
<asp:ScriptReference Name="bootstrap" />
```

but in the Bundleconfig.cs file there is nothing about them.

In what part of the project are referenced them? I want to reference them to another version.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The documentation https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.scriptreference(v=vs.110).aspx says "Name - Gets or sets the name of the embedded resource that contains the client script file. 
"

So your script is an embedded resource in the project.